# Why can't I use a literal Tab as the {commands} for :normal?

Tags: vimscript, tab-characters

I'd like to write the following code:

```
function Normal(command)
    execute "normal!" a:command
endfunction
call Normal("\<C-O>")
call Normal("\<C-I>")
```

The first call to Normal succeeds, but the second throws an error:

```
E471: Argument required
```

Indeed, you get the same error if you enter the command `:norm! ^I` with the keystrokes:

<kbd>:</kbd><kbd>n</kbd><kbd>o</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>m</kbd><kbd>!</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-I</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

I have a vague idea that the problem might be something to do with the fact that a `Tab` character is whitespace, but I'd like to know more precisely what's going on.

N.B. I've already worked around the issue by adding a count `"1\<C-I>"`, so this is purely out of curiosity.

Comment: Just to be clear, you already know command can't start with space, you want to know why it can't start with space?

Comment: @dedowsdi I'm afraid I don't understand your comment. My question is: Why doesn't `:execute "normal! \<C-I>"` do the same thing as pressing `<Ctrl-I>` in normal mode?

Comment: Well, you knew command of :norm doesn't start with space(which include Tab),  you knew \<C-I> is Tab, you knew you can add a count 1 to fix it, it confuses me.

Comment: @dedowsdi Thanks. Now I understand your comment. No, it wasn't clear to me that  `{commands} cannot start with a space` also implies that `{commands} cannot start with the byte 0x9`. (But it looks as though you're right that it does.)

Comment: ...which makes sense when you consider (which I had not) that the execute command might be in a Vimscript file--where tabs might be invisible--not necessarily on the command line.

Comment: I don't know what you are talking about.. but no....i considerd nothing, i just guessed space include tab.

Comment: @dedowsdi Okay. I didn't guess that. Hence the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I guess then what's happening is, that the `<c-i>` gets expanded to a literal tab before inserting into the typeahead buffer. So Vim basically sees the command `:norm! <tab>`, which is not a valid command. I don't know a way around and even escaping did not work.

What works, is to use the `feedkeys()` command, e.g. `:call feedkeys("\t", 'tn')`.